# Search field not working after running the below javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
  <div class="row col-lg-8  col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-2">
    <label class="switch ml-2 mr-2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch-exp" value='off'>
      <span class="slider slider2 round"></span>
    </label>
    <h5 class="mr-3 mt-2" style="font-size: 20px;">Abonos vencidos</h4>
      <br>
    <label class="switch switch-close ml-2 mr-2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch-close" checked value='on'>
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    <h5 class="mt-2" style="font-size: 20px;">Abonos por vencer</h4>
    </div>
  <!-- butt
```

```html
<span class="counter pull-top"></span>
<div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
<table class="table table-hover border results table-striped mb-0">
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Nombre / Apellido</th>
      <th>Nro documento</th>
      <th>Nro de teléfono</th>
      <th>horario</th>
      <th>Fecha vencimiento</th>
      <th>Note</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="warning no-result table-danger">
    <td colspan="7" style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> sin resultados</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% if customers %}
  {% for customer in customers %}
  <tr class="table-{{customer.category}} {{customer.category}}">
    {% if customer.user.image %}
    <th scope="row"><a href="{% url 'core:user_detail' customer.user.id %}"><img src="{{customer.user.image.url}}" alt="customer-img" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></a></th>
    {% else %}
    <th scope="row"><a href="{% url 'core:user_detail' customer.user.id %}"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Default-welcomer.png" alt="customer-img" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></a></th>
    {% endif %}
    <td>{{customer.user.first_name}}/{{customer.user.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.user.id}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.user.phone_no}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.user.time}}</td> 
      <td>{{customer.expiration_date.date}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.user.note}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    <tr class="table-{{customer.category}}">
      No hay clientes disponibles
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.switch').forEach(switchs => switchs.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
    if(event.target.id === 'switch-close'){
        if (event.target.value === 'off'){
            event.target.value='on';
            document.querySelectorAll('#danger').forEach(items => items.style.display='none');
            document.querySelectorAll('#warning').forEach(items => items.style.display='table-row');
            document.querySelectorAll('#success').forEach(items => items.style.display='none');
        }
        else if (event.target.value === 'on'){
            event.target.value = 'off';
            document.querySelectorAll('#danger').forEach(items => items.style.display='table-row');
            document.querySelectorAll('#success').forEach(items => items.style.display='table-row');
            document.querySelectorAll('#warning').forEach(items => items.style.display='table-row');
        }
    }
    else if (event.target.id==='switch-exp'){
        if (event.target.value === 'off'){
            event.target.value='on';
            document.querySelectorAll('#danger').forEach(items => items.style.display='table-row');
            document.querySelectorAll('#warning').forEach(items => items.style.display='none');
            document.querySelectorAll('#success').forEach(items => items.style.display='none');
        }
        else if (event.target.value === 'on'){
            event.target.value = 'off';
            document.querySelectorAll('#danger').forEach(items => items.style.display='table-row');
            document.querySelectorAll('#success').forEach(items => items.style.display='table-row');
            document.querySelectorAll('#warning').forEach(items => items.style.display='table-row');
        }
    }
}) )
```

[this is a gym management system i have table and the search bar which searches the data from table and there are two switches which shows that expired membership users and close to expiration membership users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUZSU.png)

when i search in the search box the tables works correctly the data found according to search field input and all the table rows are disappear but as long i click on the any switch button the search field data found but all other row don't disappear they still on the screen.the javascript is below the below javascript is not for the search field it is for the switches i click on switches than searched data displays but other fields that are not searched are not removed.

Comment: what is your html for switch button?

Comment: Add html so you can test the code.

Comment: One obvious thing is IDs must be unique. But you are trying to loop through multiple elements with the same ID using querySelectorAll. If you have multiple elements with the same ID, you will get weird results.

Comment: i have added the html for the switch buttons @D.Seah

Comment: sorry, I do not understand why you attach event to labels and not checkboxes